# Validating requests in /server url

Tags: ios, mdm

In iOS MDM /server url will be called for each operation by the device when it is woken by APNS. I have securely encrypted and signed other profiles at the time of enrollment and successfully passed the server url to device. Its working fine but I have few concerns over this server endpoint as follows.

1) Any client or entity who could send similar plist payload can invoke this service. If a 3rd party has access to a device UDID they can compose this xml payload and invoke this service. From the server point of view it will be hard to track this behavior and identify real devices. To identify that in the real scenario will it send and CMS data or related to validate this scenario?

2) Once the device hit this endpoint from server we can generate operation profiles and send back to devices. For the profiles at the enrollment time we could extract the public certificate from CMS data and encrypt from that. But for this server url how do I achieve that? Seems its not getting any cert like that from device side. Just wondering whether to save the public keys we got in earlier stages but since at the enrollment it goes through 2 SCEP calls not sure what to use it. Will those subsequent profiles payload can be encrypted using previous public cert? Right now I do the signing anyway which works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.)*** ***Any client or entity who could send similar plist payload can invoke this service. If a 3rd party has access to a device UDID they can compose this xml payload and invoke this service. From the server point of view it will be hard to track this behavior and identify real devices. To identify that in the real scenario will it send and CMS data or related to validate this scenario?***

Yes, Any client who could possess the UDID and Server URl can send a valid Plist to your server acting like the device. 

But they cannot sign the plist with the private key in the device(Which is generated during SCEP enrolment). You would be having corresponding Public key for it to validate the signature. 

To force the device to send the signature along each request to `Server URL`, you have to include `SignMessage` tag in your MDM payload and set it as true. Like this

```
<key>SignMessage</key>
     <true/>
```

So when you include this tag along with your MDM payload, you would be get the signature of Identity Private key in the Header `HTTP_MDM_SIGNATURE`.
Then you can validate the signature using your public key.

***2.)***   ***Just wondering whether to save the public keys we got in earlier stages but since at the enrollment it goes through 2 SCEP calls not sure what to use it.***

Yes I mentioned in the previous answer you should save the public certificate which is issued during SCEP phase. Later you will use that public certificate to Validate the signature from Device and Encrypt the profile you are sending.

Regarding 2 SCEP calls, First SCEP call is to generate the certificate and securely transfer the MDM Payload and actual SCEP payload which will be used as Idenitity certificate for MDM.

So you should use the second one for validating the signature and encryption.

One more hint is, you would have mentioned `IdentityCertificateUUID` in your MDM payload. The Identity Certificate SCEP payload should have same UUID as its `PayloadUUID` . That SCEP payload's certificate will be used as the identity certificate for MDM.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Seems SignMessage will do the trick and I should be able to validate it then. I just have the problem of pointing it to a 3rd party CA server which supports SCEP. In that case theoretically there should be a way or endpoint to validate these certificates upon sending it from MDM server.

Comment: @Dilshan: By the way, relying on 3rd party CA for SCEP would be very costly I suppose. There are lot of open source SCEP implementations available nowadays. You could leverage it and have your own SCEP server.

Comment: Right now I have implemented this and it works fine end to end. Enrollment flow has no issues as well. I just want to give some extension points for customers to plug 3rd party CAs. For that just figuring out the possibility. Also figuring out the catches in this enrollment flow. Just posted this question since I encountered this. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The bottom line that you want to authenticate device.

Each device has an identity cert (a cert distributed in PKCS12 or through SCEP).

Each time when a device communicate to the server it does authentication using SSL client certs.

Most of the time there is a reverse proxy sitting upfront of your web server. It could be Apache or Nginx or anything else. This reverse proxy terminates SSL connection and checks client certificate. Usually, they are configured to pass this client certificate as a header to your web application.

This way your web app can get this header, get a certificate out of it and check against your DB whether a device with specific udid (passed to your endpoint) have a certificate (passed to your webapp in the header).

I am not sure which reverse do you use and whether it's configured properly to pass the certificate.

Comment: Thanks Victor for the reply. Right now this runs on a standalone server and configuring the reverse proxy will be a deployment thing. Hence that header passing mechanism will dependent on the configuration of this reverse proxy. Since this device does client authentication I assume I can read this cert from my JAX-RS endpoint. With that certificate I should be able to validate this.

Comment: Since anyone have the ability to point my MDM server to a 3rd party Certificate Authority I cannot get the generated cert at SCEP enrollment stage. Hence I assume the place I need to look at is /profile url where the device sends its identity cert at that time as well if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Dilshan Generally I described only one of possible setups (most common). At the end of the day, something should terminate SSL, validate client cert and pass it somehow to your app. It could be done a lot of different ways.

Comment: It's interesting setup (that users can point to their own certificate authorities). Why do you have that? It's useful to certificates for WiFi and VPN. However, I don't see benefits on this for iOS MDM client certs. It's benefitial to save a certificate while SCEP enrollment. This way you can be sure that you tie a certificate to device udid correctly. However, you can probably do it at the first call to your command url (there will be a window of vulnerability)

Comment: Thanks Victor for the reply. What I meant was for each deployment clients can point to 3rd party CAs such as EJBCA. Hence x509 generation happens at that end where the MDM server is not aware of that. In normal cases this SCEP calls go through the embedded CA and in that case my MDM can track that. If so that solution will work. But as you mentioned I understand that there could be a vulnerability if we get that from endpoint. Ideally what should have happened is that, device request should have been signed by its private key where I would have verify it to check the sender.